# AttributeError: Unknown property cmap

Tags: python

I have the following 2 errors:

```
AttributeError: Unknown property cmap
```

and

```
Cannot find reference 'coolwarm' in 'cm.py'
```

I have run:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.cm as cm
```

Code I get the error with is

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax2 = ax1.twiny()

ax1.plot(result['tme'], result['spread'], ".", markersize=1, 
c=result['bdaterange'], cmap=cm.coolwarm)
```

Comment: This is not a complete code snippet since you never show us the definition of the `result` dictionary or the complete traceback. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You also need to fix the indentation of your last line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Colormap `coolwarm` is added to matplotlib since 1.1.0 ([commit](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/commit/4772c9d66e6f25b2e2e43632d836875eb6913b5f#diff-ef5eff380470cb1e91c47fe27bf3bdc3)).

Update your matplotlib after it then you'll get it working.

```
pip install --upgrade matplotlib
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be what you're trying to do (your question is a bit vague, so, I guessed).

First, some imports and random data:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as colors
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import numpy as np

xs = np.arange(10)
ys = np.arange(10,20)
# the intensity of each data point
intensities = np.random.rand(10)
```

Then, we get the colormap you wanted:

```
coolwarm = plt.get_cmap('coolwarm')
my_norm = colors.Normalize(0, 1)
map = cm.ScalarMappable(norm=my_norm, cmap='coolwarm')
```

Finally, plot each data point with its intensity as follows:

```
for idx in range(len(ys)):
    point_x = xs[idx]
    point_y = ys[idx]
    my_col = map.to_rgba(intensities[idx])
    plt.plot(point_x, point_y, ".", markersize=5, color=my_col)

plt.show()
```

For this code you get an image like this:
[random_cmap_data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhR83.png)